# Java string interning, what is guaranteed?

Tags: java, string, string-interning

The question boils down to this code:

```
// setup
String str1 = "some string";
String str2 = new String(str1);
assert str1.equals(str2);
assert str1 != str2;
String str3 = str2.intern();

// question cases
boolean case1 = str1 == "some string";
boolean case2 = str1 == str3;
```

Does Java standard give any *guarantees* about values of `case1` and `case2`?
Link to relevant part of Java spec would be nice, of course.

Yes, I looked at all the "Similar Questions" found by SO, and found no duplicates, as none I found answered the question this way. And no, this is not about the misguided idea of "optimizing" string comparisons by replacing `equals` with `==`.

Comment: If it's not a useless optimization attempt, what is it ?

Comment: @dystroy The particular case I had was about using normalized file names for synchronization, and if interned strings are safe for the purpose, or if a shared `Map<String, Object> fileNameToLockObjectMap` would be needed. Not being sure, I ended up using a Map in that case (and not going back to change).

Comment: Locking on interned Strings is not a good idea.  It is quite likely you will have unintended consequences.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I agree, when not sure, take the safe route. But can you think of other such consequences, except same interned String instance being used in completely unrelated parts of the program? And can you think of unintended consequences, if such strings are *not* used for locking elsewhere, and assuming no library uses such an ugly trick?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is your JLS quote, [Section 3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/lexical.html#3.10.5):

> Each string literal is a reference (§4.3) to an instance (§4.3.1,
>   §12.5) of class String (§4.3.3). String objects have a constant value.
>   String literals-or, more generally, strings that are the values of
>   constant expressions (§15.28)-are "interned" so as to share unique
>   instances, using the method String.intern.
>
> Thus, the test program consisting of the compilation unit (§7.3):

```
package testPackage;
class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                String hello = "Hello", lo = "lo";
                System.out.print((hello == "Hello") + " ");
                System.out.print((Other.hello == hello) + " ");
                System.out.print((other.Other.hello == hello) + " ");
                System.out.print((hello == ("Hel"+"lo")) + " ");
                System.out.print((hello == ("Hel"+lo)) + " ");
                System.out.println(hello == ("Hel"+lo).intern());
        }
}

class Other { static String hello = "Hello"; }
```

> and the compilation unit:

```
package other;

public class Other { static String hello = "Hello"; }
```

> produces the output: true true true true false true
>
> This example illustrates six points:
>
> Literal strings within the same class (§8) in the same package (§7)
>   represent references to the same String object (§4.3.1).
>
> Literal strings within different classes in the same package represent
>   references to the same String object.
>
> Literal strings within different classes in different packages
>   likewise represent references to the same String object.
>
> Strings computed by constant expressions (§15.28) are computed at
>   compile time and then treated as if they were literals.
>
> Strings computed by concatenation at run time are newly created and
>   therefore distinct. The result of explicitly interning a computed
>   string is the same string as any pre-existing literal string with the
>   same contents.

Combined with the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) for intern, and you have enough information to deduce that both of your cases will return true.

Comment: How does it work in multithread enviroment, eg. when intern() is callad multiple times from multple threads at same time. I guess that this taken care of, but that's just a guess. Do you know more about this?

Comment: @Alpedar - the implementation of intern is native and platform dependent. I presume it's thread safe based off the JavaDoc, but their is no guarantee (that I've found) in official documentation backing this up.

Answer (score 6):

I think String.intern API provides enough information

A pool of strings, initially empty, is maintained privately by the class String.

When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object) method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String object is returned.

It follows that for any two strings s and t, s.intern() == t.intern() is true if and only if s.equals(t) is true.

All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are interned. String literals are defined in section 3.10.5 of the The Java™ Language Specification.